# Same code inserts data into one database but not into another

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I am facing a strange problem right now. I am using pypyodbc to insert data into a test database hosted by AWS. This database that I created was by hand and did not imitate all relations and whatnot between tables. All I did was create a table with the same columns and the same datatypes as the original (let's call it master) database. When I run my code and insert the data it works in the test environment. Then I change it over to the master database and the code runs all the way through but no data is actually inputted. Is there any chance that there are security protocols in place which prevent me from inputting data in through the Python script rather than through a normal SQL query? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it's not pointing to the correct database.  Have you made sure the connection information changes to point to the correct DB?  So the server name is correct, the login credentials are good, etc.?

Comment: Yes I just double checked, I even pull information from the database in my script It's just that nothing is inputted even though I include execute and commit lines.

Comment: Have you tried logging into the DB as the user you are using for the ODBC connection and run the queries on their own to ensure that user is capable of doing what you need?  If the connection info is good and it works on another machine I can't think of anything other than user permissions.

Comment: ( cc: @StevenSetteducatiJr. ) ... but if is was a matter of insufficient permissions then one would expect the code to throw an error like "INSERT permission was denied" or the like. (Unless the INSERTs were done in stored procedures that sometimes "bury" exceptions as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29377756/2144390).) Steven: Can we assume that you are not ignoring any exceptions that might come back from the "master" database?

Comment: @GordThompson I am not ignoring any exceptions thrown from the database at all since this is still in the bug testing phase

Comment: @MichaelPlatt So I just realized that I hard coded the test database into the function that creates my insert into strings that are linked to a query so you were 100% right. Thank you so much!

Comment: @StevenSetteducatiJr. Great!!  I'm glad you were able to fix your problem.  Best of luck with coding!!

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I was only changing the string that is used for creating the odbc engine